# Which Entity Framework technology am I really using?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

This sounds a bit silly but I am uncertain of what it is I am actually using when I think of "Entity Framework". I noticed that when searching for documentation, I often end up with object and methods that I simply do not have or use directly (such as objectcontext, EntityState, ect). I'm also unsure of which Linq I'm using at any given time (Linq2SQL, Linq2Entities, Linq2Objects).

**What I think I'm using:**
Database-first ADO.NET Entity Data Model and Linq to Entities.

**My setup:**
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015, installed with default settings using the installer downloaded from the official website. Up to date, no additional addons, library or packaged installed.

**What I do:**

- Design a database like this and create it in SQL Server

  ```
   MyFooDB
      table Foo ( PK int Id, varchar Name)
      table Bar ( PK int Id, bit Active, FK int FooId references Foo.Id )
  ```
- Open VS2015, File > New > Project > C# > Windows >Console Application.
- In the solution explorer, right-click the project node > add > new item > Data > ADO.NET Entity data model.
- A dialog opens, I choose EF designer from Database, connect to my server and choose my database "MyFooDB". At the bottom of the dialog it says that the    setting will be saved in the app.config as "MyFooDBEntities".
- I get asked which version of Entity Framework I want to use, this time I'll choose 6.X   .
- A dialog appears for me to choose which database objects I want to include. The model namespace text field says "MyFooDBModel". I check "Foo" and "Bar" then click Finish.
- An edmx file is created and opened. I see a diagram of the objects I chose. Under the edmx file I see this structure:

  ```
  MyFooDBModel.edmx
    -MyFooDBModel.Context.tt
        -MyFooDBModel.Context.cs
    -MyFooDBModel.Designer.cs
    -MyFooDBModel.edmx.diagram
    -MyFooDBModel.tt
        -Foo.cs
        -Bar.cs
  ```
- In Program.cs, I instanciate a MyFooDBEntities and use it:

  ```
  var db = new MyFooDBEntities();
  var firstFoo = db.Foos.First(x => x.Id == 1);
  if (!firstFoo.Bars.Any())
  {
      Bar b = new Bar() { Id = 3, Active=true };
      firstFoo.Bars.Add(b);
      db.SaveChanges();
  }
  ```

And so my question is what are the different technologies I used and how do they relate to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LINQ2SQL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a completely different (and no longer supported) technology, it used to have different templates and was sort of the "quicker and simpler" version of EF (although there was no actual relationship between the two).

[`LINQ2Objects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) is the description of applying LINQ expressions to objects/instances in memory, not really the sames as either EF or L2S.

You are indeed using Entity Framework, along with the Entity Data Models (EDMX).  EDMX is a carry-over from older versions of EF where you had a design surface (remember when those were cool) for designing your data model.  With EF6.x, you can still use these and they are essentially used to generate `.cs` files for you.  This is no longer what most people would consider to be the "Best Practice" for using EF, the preferred way of generating your model now is using [Code First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907#codefirst) and POCOs.

Under the hood, EF 6.x still has a lot of legacy dependency on the EDMX paradigm and so the code first and fluent configurations are used to build this up to some extent, so I don't *think* there is any significant functional differences between the two.  But generally speaking code first is much easier to work with, maintain, and for 3rd parties to understand your code.

With Entity Framework Core (formerly Entity Framework 7), it's been completely re-written and the EDMX models are no longer supported, so for that reason alone you might consider ditching them (not sure if or what the migration path is between 6 and Core).

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to get up to date but I was confused by all the similar terminology so I prefered to ask before reading up on something obsolete.